# What are the different types of databinding and when do you use what?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata

I want to understand better when you use one-way databinding, two-way databinding, livedata binding only databinding and i even saw one with some kind of lifecycleowner. Ive been trying to understand this topic for hours but i think i am more confused right now than anything. Thanks for any help

Comment: so what about the binding do you have a problem with?  https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-data-binding-binding-to-livedata-one-and-two-way-binding-dae1cd68530f

Comment: I dont know which type of DataBinding to use, and also why and how to combine LiveData with DataBinding

Answer (score 0):

- Oneway databinding is used, when the data flows only from the ViewModel to the UI.
- Twoway databinding also allows the data to flow from the UI to the ViewModel (e.g. input in EditText).
- Besides "normal" properties, also LiveData properties can be directly bound to the UI.
- As LiveData is Lifecycle-aware, you need to specify an lifecycle owner when you bind LiveData properties.